# Test if children of react element are not crossing the parent outline

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

Is there a way to test that sub-components/children of React element are not crossing the parent outline?

For example:

[image: demonstration]

in the above picture, the test should fail as the child is crossing the `outline` of the parent

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/child-crossing-parent-v9gzu?file=/src/App.js) with the components

**Note:**

Using the element [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) return `0` for all properties (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, etc...)

Comment: This isn't something you can unit test in a terminal, the components necessarily need to be rendered into a view non-virtually. This wouldn't even be unit test since you are testing how two components (units) interact (integrate) with one another. For this you'll need something like cypress or puppeteer to run an integration test and measure the rendered DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the answer but I hoped I was wrong…

Comment: @DrewReese you can post your comment as an answer and I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you can unit test via CLI/test runner, the components necessarily need to be rendered into a "live" view, not into any virtual DOM, like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) used by many unit test runners. Note that even jest snapshots compare only the DOM structure and not the computed view.

This also would not be considered a unit test since you are now testing how two components (units) interact (integrate) with one another.

For this you'll need something like [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), or [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to run an integration test and measure the rendered DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersectionObserver which will fire an event when the child get in the viewport of the parent. actually there is a react wraper for it [react-intersection-observer](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer)

Comment: Thanks! but I don't see how can I use it in my testing, isn't the purpose of it is for production rather than for testing?